# group_by() with two counts, one per variable

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this

```
PDB.ID Chain.ID Space.Group     Uniprot.Recommended.Name
101M        A         P 6   Myoglobin
102L        A    P 32 2 1   Endolysin
102M        A         P 6   Myoglobin
103L        A    P 32 2 1   Endolysin
103M        A         P 6   Myoglobin
104L        A       H 3 2   Endolysin
```

After reading the data and loading the required package

```
df <- read.delim("~/Downloads/dummy2.tsv")
library(dplyr)
```

I can count the number of entries for a specific variable with code like this

```
df %>% count(Uniprot.Recommended.Name)
```

Or alternatively

```
df %>% +
group_by(Uniprot.Recommended.Name) %>% +
  summarise( +
    count = n() +
)
```

I get two columns, a count for every case of `Uniprot.Recommended.Name`

My question: Is it possible to get a table with two counts. Counting the number of entries for every `Space.Group` per `Uniprot.Recommended.Name`.

Expected table should be like something like this

```
Myoglobin    P 6         123
Myoglobin    P 32 2 1    124
Endolysin    P 32 2 1    125
Endolysin    H 3 2       126
```

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry for the images, I do not know how to input tables.

Comment: 1. Please don't post links to data, or screenshots of results, instead provide sample data in your post.  See [mcve], also see [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting posts if you're not sure how to input data.  2. [`group_by()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) accepts multiple arguments.  that should accomplish your goal.

Comment: And also `count` accepts multiple arguments. So `df %>% count(Uniprot.Recommended.Name, Space.Group)` should work.

Comment: @andrew_reece, sorry I will edit my post.  I did look into the link you provided but I did not see anything with respect to tables. I'll try to do my best.

Comment: @RonakShah Would you mind creating the answer. It works.

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked. Actually, this has been asked and answered before. I have marked it as a duplicate of that post. I hope that is fine.

Comment: @RonakShah Great.